# angularjs nested detail view doesn't get displayed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

the stateProvider of my app have a nested view (base.gallery -> base.gallery.detail) and if i click on a link inside my gallery it should show the detailview, but it doesn't...

the link looks good for me, but it only changes the url in the browser and it logs "get displayed" from the onEnter-function, but it doesn't display the template("modules/album/detail/view/detail.html") in my ui-view...

e.g.: for my link `<a ui-sref="base.photos.detail(params(item.id))" class="list-item-link" href="/gallery/21/detail/457">`

```
   .state("base", {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'modules/base/views/base.html',
        controller: function($scope, navigationData){
            $scope.navigation.data = navigationData;
         },

        resolve:{
            navigationData:function(navigationSvc){
                var response = navigationSvc;
                return response;
            }
        }
    })
    .state("base.categories", {
        url: "/categories",
        templateUrl: "modules/album/list/view/list.html",
        controller: function($scope, data){
            $scope.settings.data = data;
            $scope.settings.type = "categories";
         },
        resolve:{
            data:function(listSvc){
                var response = listSvc.load("categories");
                return response;
            }
        }
    })
    .state("base.category", {
        url: "/category/:id",
        templateUrl: "modules/album/list/view/list.html",
        controller: function($scope, data){
            $scope.settings.data = data;
            $scope.settings.type = "galleries";         
         },
        resolve:{
            data:function($stateParams, listSvc){
                var response = listSvc.load("category/"+$stateParams.id);
                return response;
            }
        },
    })
.state("base.gallery", {
        url: "/gallery/:id",
        templateUrl: "modules/album/list/view/list.html",
        controller: function($scope, data, $stateParams){
            $scope.settings.data = data;
            $scope.settings.type = "photos";
         },
        resolve:{
            data:function($stateParams, listSvc){
                var response = listSvc.load("gallery/"+$stateParams.id);
                return response;
            }
        }
    })

    .state("base.gallery.detail", {
        url: "/detail/:photo_id",
        templateUrl: "modules/album/detail/view/detail.html",
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
            console.log("doesn't get displayed ");
            $scope.settings.type = "photo";
        },

        onEnter: function(){
            console.log("get displayed");
        }
    })
```

html of my index where i load all my lists and i als want to display my detail view inside that ui-view...

```
...
<div class="content" ui-view></div>
...
```

html of my list view

```
<li class="list-item" ng-repeat="item in list.data">
    <a ui-sref="{{state}}(params(item.id))" class="list-item-link">item.title</a>
</li>
```

**UPDATE**

k i got it ;) i need views and then use the @ to target it in the same ui-view from my index.html

```
.state("base.gallery.detail", {
    url: "/detail/:photo_id",
    views:{
      "@" : {
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams, listSvc){
          $scope.settings = {};
          $scope.settings.type = "photos";
          $scope.photo = listSvc.data[$stateParams.id_photo-1];
          console.log($stateParams);
        },
        template: "<h2>detail</2><div>{{photo.title}}</div>"
      } 
});
```